# When do the results from a mapper task get deleted from disk?

Tags: hadoop

When do the outputs for a mapper task get deleted from the local filesystem?  Do they persist until the entire job completes or do they get deleted at an earlier time than that?

Comment: You mean, when are they deleted from the temporary HDFS folder on each datanode?

Comment: No, the results of the mapper tasks are saved `hadoop.tmp.dir` which is a directory on the local file system, not hdfs

Comment: Youch, sorry.  Of course they're not stored in HDFS.  My mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the map and reduce tasks, two further tasks are created: a job setup task
and a job cleanup task. These are run by tasktrackers and are used to run code to setup
the job before any map tasks run, and to cleanup after all the reduce tasks are complete.
The OutputCommitter that is configured for the job determines the code to be run, and
by default this is a FileOutputCommitter. For the job setup task it will create the final
output directory for the job and the temporary working space for the task output, and
for the job cleanup task it will delete the temporary working space for the task output.

Have a look at [OutputCommitter.](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/OutputCommitter.html)

Answer (score 2):

If your `hadoop.tmp.dir` is set to a default setting (say, /tmp/), it will most likely be subject to `tmpwatch` and any default settings in your OS.  I would suggest poking around in `/etc/cron.d/`, `/etc/cron.daily`, `etc/cron.weekly/`, etc., to see exactly what your OS default is like.

One thing to keep in mind about `tmpwatch` is that, by default, it will key on access time, not modification time (i.e., files that have not been 'touched' since X will be considered 'stale' and subject to removal).  However, it's a common practice with Hadoop to mount filesystems with the `noatime` and `nodiratime` flags, meaning that access times will not get updated and thus skewing your tmpwatch behaviors.

Otherwise, Hadoop will purge task attempt logs older than 24 hours (after task completion), by default.  While a few years old, [this writeup](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2010/11/hadoop-log-location-and-retention/) has some great info on the default behaviors.  Take a look in particular at the sections that refer to `mapreduce.job.userlog.retain.hours`.

EDIT: responding to OP's comment, which clears up my misunderstanding of the question:

As far as the intermediate output of map tasks which is spilled to disk, used by any combiners, and copied to any reducers, the Hadoop Definitive Guide has this to say:

> Tasktrackers do not delete map outputs from disk as soon as the first
>   reducer has retrieved them, as the reducer may fail. Instead, they
>   wait until they are told to delete them by the jobtracker, which is
>   after the job has completed.

[Source](https://www.inkling.com/read/hadoop-definitive-guide-tom-white-3rd/chapter-6/shuffle-and-sort)

I've also +1'd @mgs answer below, as they have linked the source code that controls this and described the Job cleanup task.

So, **yes**, the map output data is deleted immediately after the job completes, successfully or not, and no sooner.

Comment: Thanks but I'm asking about the output written by individual mappers that is retained and then copied to the reducers, not the log files for the individual tasks.  The outputs of the mappers are eventually deleted by Hadoop before the task is completed, however, when this clean up occurs is the focus of my question.

Answer (score 1):

"Tasktrackers do not delete map outputs from disk as soon as the first reducer has retrieved them, as the reducer may fail. Instead, they wait until they are told to delete them by the jobtracker, which is after the job has completed"

Hadoop: The Definitive Guide ( Section 6.4)