# When Intermediate Mapper Output files will be deleted, as soon as Mapper finishes or start of Reducer

Tags: java, hadoop

When would be Intermediate Output files are deleted from Mapper? 
Is it after completion of Mapper job or when data moved to Reducer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18279485/when-do-the-results-from-a-mapper-task-get-deleted-from-diskGive reply if its the answer for your question